# Sorting the List of Type Dto with List <String> contacting Ids in java

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

I have a `List` of objects like this:

```
List<Student> student= new ArrayList<Student>();
```

`Student` class looks like:

```
public class Student {
    private String Id;
    private String name;
}
```

I have another `List<String> stuIds = new ArrayList<String>();`

I want to sort `student` list based on `stuIds` list.

Tried this, but not getting the right order:

```
student.forEach(Id -> {
            
    student.sort(Comparator.comparing(items->stuIds.indexOf(student.getId())));     
});
```

AND

```
Collections.sort(student, 
    Comparator.comparing(item -> stuIds.indexOf(item)));
});
```

Is the sorting not happening because it is `List<Dto>` and `List<String>`? Could someone help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stuIds.indexOf(item)` will always return `-1` since `item` is a `Student` and `stuIds` contains `String`s.

Try:

```
Collections.sort(student, 
    Comparator.comparing(item -> stuIds.indexOf(item.getID())));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to solving this problem:

**Approach 1: Using a HashMap for fast sorting**

This will take extra `space` but will be `faster` than normal sorting for your scenario:

```
List<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();
List<String> stuIds = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, Student> stringStudentHashMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Student student1 : student) {
    stringStudentHashMap.put(student1.getId(), student1);
}
ArrayList<Student> sortedStudent = new ArrayList<>();
for (String stuId : stuIds) {
    sortedStudent.add(stringStudentHashMap.get(stuId));
}
```

**Approach 2: Using java Comparator:**

You are not able to get the required result because you are trying to get the index of the `Student` object (instead of `studentId`) in the `studentId` List. Try changing the code with below code:

```
Collections.sort(student,Comparator.comparing(t -> stuIds.indexOf(t.getId())));
```